# scala nested for comprehension with futures

Tags: scala, for-loop, future

My case domain classes are as below

```
case class Account(randomId: String, accounts: List[String]) // for each of accounts i need to get AccountProfiles.

case class AccountProfiles(actId: String, profiles: List[String], additionalInfo: Map[String, String], ......)

case class AccountInfo(id: String, profiles:List[String]) // for each of AccountProfiles I need to construct AccountInfo
```

my access layer implementation signature to extract above domain classes look like below

```
getLinked(): Future[Account]
getAccountProfile(actId: String): Future[AccountProfiles]
```

Can I have a `for` comprehension to construct `Future` list of `AccountInfo` domain object with the help of `getLinked` and `getAccountProfile` methods ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. I think this is what you're looking for assuming AccountProfiles.actId and AccountInfo.id are supposed to be equivalent.

```
for {
  account <- getLinked()
  profiles <- Future.sequence(account.accounts map { id => getAccountProfile(id) })
} yield profiles map { p => AccountInfo(p.actId, p.profiles) }
```

Comment: can i know how to handle the exceptions in this flow ?